# Print Friendly Page Tab

Tags: css, printing, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-iframe

I have a FB app that displays a fan-gated coupon for our page's fans.  When you go to print the coupon, Facebook's right-hand sidebar plops itself right in the middle of the page.

I tried to print the iFrame only via javascript, but Facebook didn't like that.  I'm assuming they wouldn't allow a popup either, but we wouldn't want to do a popup anyway.

Is there any other way to trick the page into being more print-friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already run into similar issue to,

My solution have been to create a link bringing user out of Facebook with a print friendly code coupon. You could use `<a target="_blank">` or just changing the `window.top.location` to your printable page.

Hope this help!

Comment: I found that by simply adding a print button inside the iFrame, the action of clicking the button brought the iframe into focus.  In the case of Chrome, at least, only the element in focus is printed, so this solved it.